# JPA one to one mapping throws "Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

Hello im having issues with saving entities in spring boot, my classes look like this

```java
@Table(name = "team")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@With
public class Team {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private String teamName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TeamMember> teamMembers;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "team")
    private InvitationLink invitationLink;
}
```

and

```java
@Entity
@Data
@With
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "invitationLink")
public class InvitationLink {
    @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Team team;

    @Column
    private String invitationNumbers;
}
```

the problem in this situation is when i try and save these objects.
Im saving them like this

```java
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void createTeam(UserDto userDto, TeamDto teamDto) throws JSONException {
        // Some unrelated code here    
        InvitationLink invitationLink = new InvitationLink();
        invitationLink.setInvitationNumbers(StringUtils.generateShortUUID());
        invitationLink.setTeam(team);
        team.setInvitationLink(invitationLink);
        invitationLinkRepository.save(invitationLink);
        teamRepository.save(team);
        userRepository.save(user);
        teamMemberRepository.save(teamMember);
    }
```

The main problem is that when i try to save there entities i get error.
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
Does anybody know how to fix this?
I have tried switching ways to map these entities but I didnt get anywhere, at one point i got another error thats recursion but thats completely different story...

Answer (score 0):

In both your entities you use `Cascade.ALL`, which means that e.g. your `InvitationLink` is able to save changes for `Team`. Therefore when you save your InvitationLink it already updates your Team. So the solution could be to either change the `Cascade` or remove the redundant save calls.

Comment: t does work, but object Team doesn't store invitationLinksId. Its null.

Comment: That's because of your mappedBy field in Team. With this you give Spring the information that this relation is bi-directional and tell them where they can find the column to join. So what happens is that if you get a Team by the ID jpa looks into the invitation table and gets the invitation with the ID of the team. So you should be able to remove this column in you team table. You could just test if it works correctly by finding the team with ur ID and there you should see the invitationLink